# SSIS Derived Column split first parentheses of characters

Tags: ssis, multiple-columns, derived

Im trying to workout how to write an expression in the derived Column task, to extract a readcode e.g (XXXX) from another column

```
ID | Ethnicity             | ReadCode
-------------------------------------
 1 | (XXXX) White British  | (XXXX)
```

So far i have the expression SUBSTRING(Ethnicity,1,FINDSTRING(Ethnicity,")",1) - 1)

But it throws up an error that the characters had no match? obviously i'm completely barking up the wrong tree with this expression, but how on earth do find (XXXX) and extract?

Comment: try using the following in derived column !`SUBSTRING(ethnicity,CHARINDEX('(',ethnicity)+1,charindex(')',ethnicity,CHARINDEX('(',ethnicity))-2)`

Comment: TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
       ------------------------------

Error at Import Ethnicity Data [Derived Column [180]]: Parsing the expression "!SUBSTRING(Ethnicity,CHARINDEX('(',Ethnicity)+1,charindex(')',Ethnicity,CHARIND‌​EX('(',Ethnicity))-2)" failed. The single quotation mark at line number "1", character number "32", was not expected.

Comment: ok! try one last time ! `SUBSTRING(ethnicity,CHARINDEX('(',ethnicity)+1,charindex(')',ethnicity))`

Comment: Error at Import Ethnicity Data [Derived Column [180]]: Parsing the expression "SUBSTRING(Ethnicity,CHARINDEX('(',Ethnicity)+1,charindex(')',Ethnicity))" failed. The single quotation mark at line number "1", character number "31", was not expected.

Comment: With double quotes around brackets the error is: function charindex was not recognized

Comment: charindex is an SQL function,not SSIS function

Comment: It would probably be easier to use a Script Component and use C#/VB.NET tools for this.

Comment: @shree-pat18,   probably, but that defeats the purpose of this exercise

Comment: in sql i can use                                                   `Select SUBSTRING(Ethnicity,CHARINDEX('(',ethnicity)+1,charindex(')',ethnicity,charindex('(',ethnicity))-2)  From <table>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an elegant solution, but this appeared to work when I tested it:

```
"(" + SUBSTRING(Ethnicity,(FINDSTRING(Ethnicity,"(",1) + 1),(FINDSTRING(Ethnicity,")",1) - 2)) + ")"
```

Let me know.

Comment: `[Flat File Source [12]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Ethnicity" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".` think im going wrong elsewhere now

Comment: @ Peter_R Problem i have now is that when i get down to row 3754 the text exceeds the length given in derived column, so i cant answer your answer as yet

Comment: @user31891 Can you not use the Advanced Edit option in the derived column to increase the output length of the column

Comment: I found that: `"(" + SUBSTRING(Ethnicity,(FINDSTRING(Ethnicity,"(",1) + 1),(FINDSTRING(Ethnicity,")",1) - 2))` worked because i was getting an extra ) at the end. thanks to Peter_R

Comment: @user31891 Ah ok, as I said it wasn't an elegant solution but glad you solved it.

Comment: Unfortunately there are sometimes nulls in the field so now i have an error because of that is there away around that?